# Sharepoint document library folders

Tags: sharepoint-2010, directory, document-library

I've got a problem "browsing" folders in my Sharepoint 2010 document library.
In my opinion there are two ways of accessing folders, but I can't see the difference.
1) http://hostname/doclib/fodler/subfolder/secondsubfolder
and
2) http://hostname/doclib/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Ffolder%2Fsubfolder%2Fsecondsubfolder&FolderCTID=0x012000C77CAA95BDB1F64190861DEBBE604440&View={03FE35CE-2568-4C17-89E1-95793E6BE73B}

Both work great as long as I'm making no changes to AllItems.aspx, but I got a problem when customizing my AllItems.aspx. My DocLib is loosing it's view in the settings and I'm getting " The webpage cannot be found " in option 1). Probably the problem is the custom page  itself or the view, but I can't see the exact problem.

What I want to do is: Display a custom webpart-page instead of the commom AllItems.aspx, but access it exactly the way sharepoint does with AllItems.aspx. Option 2) might work but needs to access the exact folder and view by guid right? So it's not quite easy to achive this dynamically.

What I tried: I Replaced the complete sourcecode of AllItems.aspx with the sourcecode of my custom webpart page.

Has anybody an idea, how I could solve this?

Thanks in advance
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AllItems.aspx is just a web part page and can be edited as such. Just add/remove the web parts from there and keep the page in place.

I've often customised the column layouts by adding a JS webpart above the WP that outputs the list items in the AllItems (and other views).

Comment: But how does SharePoint translate the parametrized url http://hostname/doclib/folder/subfolder/secondsubfolder to the equivalent Folder . After changing my AllItems.aspx I get "The webpage cannot be found".

Comment: It uses the QueryString params to pass to the Web Part containing the list items, which then filters accordingly.

Comment: That's exactly what i thought, too. But where in my aspx can I find this? And how can I (re)build this functionality? I works great as long as I make no changes to AllItems.aspx, but after changing to a combination of my custom webpart and xslt listview, I get "The webpage cannot be found" because this functionality ist missing.

Comment: AFAIK, the XSLT View is a snapshot of the list at the time of conversion. It needs plenty of work to make it dynamic again (not used this option for many years). Can you elaborate as to what you are trying to do on this custom page? There may be a simpler way.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot Paul!

What I'm trying to do is extending the navigation of the document library. 
There is no out of the box solution, to browse your folders in the document library comfortable in my opinion.

Comment: That's why I built a webpart analyzing the folder-structure and building direct links to the folders. It works great as long as I just add it to AllItems.aspx. It creats links like 1) http://hostname/doclib/fodler/subfolder/secondsubfolder.

Comment: But after modifying AllItems.aspx in designer to achive a more complex pagelayout including additional lists for example, the standard view(the only one I'm using) get's lost in the settings and so the logic behind schema 1) does AFAIK the dependency between the aspx, the view and the doclib get's broken.

Comment: I don't want to produce links like 2) http://hostname/doclib/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Ffolder%2Fsubfolder%2Fsecondsubfolder&FolderCTID=0x012000C77CAA95BDB1F64190861DEBBE604440&View={03FE35CE-2568-4C17-89E1-95793E6BE73B} because they are much more complex and depend on a special aspx file and also seem to depend on special views, while the other "link-schema" is lightweight and much more flexible.

Comment: Can you not use the Windows Explorer view of the document libraries, ie: \\hostname\doclib\folder\subfolder\secondsubfolder ?

Comment: No, explorer view only shows one document library. I need a solution to see for example two document libraries customized by special views at the same time in the browser while still being able to navigate through the folderstructure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6580/discussion-between-paul-leigh-and-stefan-hennicken)